# How can I map an optional into a primitive optional?

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

I know I can map an `Optional` into an another wrapper type optional.

```
Optional<Long> millis(Date date) {
    return ofNullable(date).map(Date::getTime);
}
```

How can I `map` or `flatMap` into an `OptionalLong`?

```
OptionalLong millis(Date date) {
}
```

I tried but had no luck.

```
ofNullable(value).flatMap(v -> { // javac has never liked me
    return OptionalLong.of(v.getTime());
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `map` to get an `Optional<OptionalLong>` then `orElse` to remove the outer `Optional` like this:

```
OptionalLong millis(Date date) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(date).map(Date::getTime)
            .map(OptionalLong::of).orElse(OptionalLong.empty());
}
```

Another (shorter in this case) way is to use the ternary operator instead:

```
OptionalLong millis(Date date) {
    return date == null ? OptionalLong.empty() : OptionalLong.of(date.getTime());
}
```

Or if you already have the `Optional<Long>`:

```
OptionalLong toOptionalLong(Optional<Long> o) {
    return o.map(OptionalLong::of).orElse(OptionalLong.empty());
}
OptionalLong toOptionalLong(Optional<Long> o) {
    return o.isPresent() ? OptionalLong.of(o.get()) : OptionalLong.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that you **will** take a performance hit in this scenario if you involve `Optional<Long>` in any way. From Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java, 3rd Edition*:

"Returning an optional that contains a boxed primitive type is prohibitively expensive compared to returning the primitive type because the optional has two levels of boxing instead of zero. [...] Therefore **you should never return an optional of a boxed primitive type**, with the possible exception of the "minor primitive types," `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Character`, `Short`, and `Float`"

There is no reason to involve `Optional` here. The best solution is to do the null check yourself, and then return an `OptionalLong`, e.g.

```
OptionalLong millis(Date date) {
    return date == null ? OptionalLong.empty() : OptionalLong.of(date.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Well, to say that "There is no reason" is imho highly subjective. One simple reason might be readability. With java we don't always strive for the most efficient solution, as long as both have the same O-runtime (like `O(1)` in this case). Also the code provided by OP might just be an example. If you already have an `Optional<Long>`, we might want to go with the "nicer" solution

Comment: Ok, readability might be a valid reason. My main objection is that you end up with code that looks really nice, but behind the scenes is unnecessarily going from `long` to `Long` to `Optional<Long>` to `Long` to `long` to `OptionalLong`

Answer (score 1):

Using the [StreamEx library](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```java
OptionalLong millis(final Date date) {  
   return StreamEx.ofNullable(date).mapToLong(Date::getTime).findAny();
}
```

or

```
OptionalLong toLong(Optional<Long> o) {
    return  StreamEx.of(o).mapToLong(Long::longValue).findAny();
}
```

or

```
OptionalLong toLong(final Optional<Date> o) {
    return StreamEx.of(o).mapToLong(Date::getTime).findAny();
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: optional is used as an argument in the code snippets only for demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it as follows:

```
OptionalLong toOptionalLong(Optional<Long> optionalValue) {
    return optionalValue.map(OptionalLong::of).orElseGet(OptionalLong::empty);
}
```

The function `OptionalLong::empty` is called if and only if the `optionalValue` is empty.

But I'm not sure I would cast an `Optional<Long>` into an `OptionalLong` unless I'm really obliged to. As said in former answers, using a ternary operator is probably a better approach in this case.